# Windows Subsytem for Linux - running applications that use openGL

Tags: qt, opengl, ubuntu-14.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am able to run a number of GUI applications successfully on windows subsystem for linux (WSL), Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS, using X-forwarding (via MobaXterm).

I recently tried to run an application that uses OpenGL. Although the GUI opens, there are a number of errors and some aspects of the GUI don't work properly. The errors are:

```
QT error: 1
QT error: <PyQt5.QtCore.QMessageLogContext object at 0x7f88e21d9ba8>
QT error: QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-user'
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

I can get rid of the `swrast` error by setting `export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1` but the other errors remain:

```
QT error: 1
QT error: <PyQt5.QtCore.QMessageLogContext object at 0x7fed3689e828>
QT error: QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-user'
```

A typical error when attempting to use part of the GUI is:

```
WARNING: QT error: 1                                                                                   (Gui.qtMessageHandler:51)
WARNING: QT error: <PyQt5.QtCore.QMessageLogContext object at 0x7f9b35e7b6d8>                          (Gui.qtMessageHandler:51)
WARNING: QT error: QOpenGLWidget: Failed to make context current                                       (Gui.qtMessageHandler:51)
```

I can run `glxgears`, but I realise this only checks a fraction of OpenGLs functions. If I run `glmark2` I get the following:

```
glmark2
** GLX does not support GLX_EXT_swap_control or GLX_MESA_swap_control!
** Failed to set swap interval. Results may be bounded above by refresh rate.
Error: Glmark2 needs OpenGL(ES) version >= 2.0 to run (but version string is: '1.4 (4.0.0 - Build 10.18.10.4358)')!
Error: main: Could not initialize canvas
```

If I run `find /usr -iname "*libGL.so*" -exec ls -l -- {} +` suggested on this link https://askubuntu.com/questions/541343/problems-with-libgl-fbconfigs-swrast-through-each-update I get the following output but I'm not sure if this indicates an error or not?

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     14 Jan 12  2016 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 -> libGL.so.1.2.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 413968 Jan 12  2016 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0
```

Running `glxinfo` seems to indicate the on-chip graphics card is used (there is a separate AMD graphics card but I don't think it's necessary to use that).

```
glxinfo | grep render
direct rendering: No (LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT set)
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer,
OpenGL renderer string: Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000
```

How can I successfully run OpenGL applications via WSL?

Comment: Any command line example to reproduce those errors?

Comment: @Biswapriyo The Qt errors I think are specific to the particular programme I am trying to run. However, based on quite a lot of posts online, I think they originate from problems with the OpenGL installed. `glxgears`, `glmark2` and `glxinfo` can all be run on the WSL (Ubuntu) command line or installed with apt-get